# Networkx bipartite graphs: nodes of different sets with the same number

Tags: python, networkx, bipartite

I encountered a major problem while constructing a bipartite graph with Networkx.

I take the nodes from a 2-columns csv, say

```
CODINV2;APPLN_ID

1;3
1;4
1;5
2;3
2;6
3;6
4;12
```

After moving each column into a separate list the code to store the nodes is

```
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(codinv, bipartite=0)
G.add_nodes_from(app_id, bipartite=1)
```

Then i add the edges (based on the csv rows):

```
for index,row in appl.iterrows():
    G.add_edge(row['APPLN_ID'], row['CODINV2'])
```

Now the links are actually created, but if i look again at nodes attributes, now many of them are wrongly considered as

```
bipartite=1
```

Basically if two nodes belonging to different sets have the same number a lot of confusion seems to arise, especially in terms of an hypothetical one mode projection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that the graph stores the node by its name.

If it enters one node by name `3` and thinks `bipartite=1`, say and then later adds `3` again, it interprets that as the same node.  If this time you tell it `bipartite=0`, it will overwrite the old entry.  So now, node `3` has `bipartite=0`.

If you want to store two different node `3`'s, then they will have to have different names.  You could try doing it as strings: `'3a'` and `'3b'`.  Or any other names, but `3` and `3` will not work.

Comment: yes, i was also thinking to a solution like that.. thanks for the response!!